# Как сделать выдвижное меню?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, анимация, qt-designer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где-то я видел, что из `Label`, можно сделать выдвигающуюся меню, как мне сделать в левой части выдвигающуюся менюшку?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Apex.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1209, 748)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 751))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 197, 121, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.spravka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 690, 111, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 690, 61, 41))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer4.png"))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 200, 81, 41))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer2.png"))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 141, 121))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Изображения/logo.png"))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 1051, 71))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 130, 241, 2))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 261, 161))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(194, 194, 194);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 720, 201, 20))
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, -2, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 360, 261, 161))
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(309, 391, 161, 2))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(331, 219, 121, 2))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(870, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(897, 200, 201, 2))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Версия"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1.0 BETA"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Всё для вас!"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "справка"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.menuvisible = 0
    def hidemenu(self):
        self.menu.hide()
    def showmenu(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.menu, b'size')
        self.anim.setDuration(500)
        if self.menuvisible==0:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(0,0))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(100, 100))
            self.menuvisible = 1
        else:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(100,100))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(0, 0))
            self.menuvisible = 0
            self.anim.finished.connect(self.hidemenu)
        self.menu.show()
        self.anim.start()


    def initUI(self):

        button = QPushButton("menu")
        button.setObjectName("button")
        button.clicked.connect(self.showmenu)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        button.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        vbox.addStretch(1)

        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
        frame.setLineWidth(1)
        
        self.menu = QFrame()
        self.menu.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;") 
        self.menu.setLineWidth(1)
        self.menu.setMinimumWidth(0);
        self.menu.hide()
        menusizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        menusizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        menusizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.menu.setSizePolicy(menusizePolicy)
        button1 = QPushButton("button1")
        button2 = QPushButton("button2")
        button3 = QPushButton("button3")
        mvbox = QVBoxLayout()
        mvbox.addWidget(button1)
        mvbox.addWidget(button2)
        mvbox.addWidget(button3)
        mvbox.addStretch(1)
        self.menu.setLayout(mvbox)       


        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        hbox.addWidget(self.menu)
        hbox.addWidget(frame)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А можно это сделать как-то плавно?

Comment: что значит плавно

Comment: У вас открывается резкими движениями и как я понял, у вас анимация стоит на кнопку, а мне нужно чтобы Qframe анимировался

Comment: QFrame и анимируется (self.menu). На счет плавности сказать ничего не могу, у меня все происходит плавно. Поиграйтесь с временем анимации (self.anim.setDuration(500))

Answer (score 1):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, i, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False,
            objectName=f'button{i}'
        )
        self.toggle_button.setFixedSize(75, 75)
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)

        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not checked
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)
        
class LeftWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget) 
        
        for i in range(2):
            box = CollapsibleBox(i, "")
            vlay.addWidget(box)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            for j in range(2):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label {}-{}".format(i, j))
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                label.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setMaximumWidth(150)
                label.setMinimumHeight(25)
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(i, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
                lay.addWidget(label)

            box.setContentLayout(lay)
            
        vlay.addStretch()        
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        vlay.addWidget(self.label_2)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget) 

        self.leftWindow = LeftWindow()
        self.leftWindow.setMaximumWidth(150)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        
        layout.addWidget(self.leftWindow, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser_2, 0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

qss = '''
#button0 {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-image: url(Ok.png);        
}
#button0:checked {
    border-image: url(lena-2.png); 
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не то, я хотел сделать как у Вандерсона, нажимаешь на кнопку и меню увеличивается, выше есть ответ на этот вопрос, но при уменьшении, у меня Qframe исчезает

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер вы задали вопрос: "Как сделать выдвижное меню?", где там написано что вы имели в виду?

Comment: моя ошибка. Сейчас я задам новый вопрос, у меня почему-то Qlabel исчезает